# synchronization going backwards

Tags: monerod, synchronization

Synchronization appears to be going backwards. im 700 blocks behind, but it moves to 701 then 702. It keeps repeating synchronization started as if it stops and starts again. Sometimes it just stops altogether.

Comment: Are you stuck on a certain block?

Answer (score 1):

That's because your daemon isn't getting new blocks however the blockchain is advancing the reason your "falling behind" is because you are on a specific block say 100 and the blockchain is at 110 your daemon says 10 blocks behind. now a new block is found block 111 your daemon now says 11 blocks behind because it is still on block 100. So synchronisation isn't going backwards it's just stopped.